# F5 - A10 Load Balacer Migration

Tags: load-balancing, f5

Does anyone have experience with a load balancer migration from F5 to A10? I'm new to both F5 & A10 devices but I managed to export the VIPs, backend IPs, Ports etc from F5 in JSON object and dumped the JSON on A10 device. I used A10's API in python to parse and create a test partition, virtual servers, service groups, and servers.

I have run out of ideas on how I can automate the export/import of Profiles (SSL, protocols, and services) from F5 to A10. This may not be a straightforward process to automate but I would appreciate any idea on how I can achieve this manually.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can download your certificates and keys from the F5 using sftp.

Certificates are in: /config/filestore/files_d/Common_d/certificate_d

Keys are in: /config/filestore/files_d/Common_d/certificate_key_d

The naming of the files is a mess but you can rename them.

The F5s have a REST API called iControl that you can use to retrieve all of the profile information that you are looking for.  There's several different SDKs available for working with it.

Comment: Thanks Jason, that was helpful. But I'm still trying to figure out how I can know which VIPs utilize which SSL certificates etc, the F5 UI not helping me on this, it doesn't show explicitly associated ssl cert for each VIP - I may be missing something here how to find out.

Comment: In the admin console go to: Local Traffic -> Virtual Servers.  Click on the virtual server.  Look athe the SSL Profile (Client) value.  Now go to Local Traffic -> Profiles -> SSL -> Client and click on the SSL Profile that was listed for the virtual server.  The certificate key chain will let you know.  Format is {Cert}/{Key}/{Chain Certs}